# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Actually I am getting no error until me not using redux connect in my component.
After using connect i am getting this error.. I don't know why and how it's happening?

I checked Everything that is highlighted when and why this error occur. but nothing found wrong with my code..

```
 const Register = ({ setAlert }) => {
     const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
         name: '',
         email: '',
      });
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have only one instance of React in your app? Can there be any external libs with its own React instance?

Comment: how check that ?

Comment: Do you use any third-party or your own external components libraries in your app?

Comment: And yeah, your component should return some jsx, string or null

Comment: npx create-react-app installed

Comment: i told i returning jsx form

Comment: tell me how i can  show you whole code

Comment: You getting this error because connect is HOC. Here you can read about using redux with hooks - https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks

Comment: yeah Iread about that so what alternative are connect..

Comment: and how we can use connect or its's alternative now

Comment: may opinion, you should read the article till the end, there are examples and explanations

Comment: thank you so much Georgiy Dubrov... i got solution